# For each $p<0$, can we find c such that $\left| \frac{x}{|x|^p}-\frac{y}{|y|^p} \right|\le c|y-x|(|x|^{-p}+|y-x|^{-p})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, inequality

As stated in the title, I need help showing (or disproving) that for each $p<0$ there exists some $c>0$ such that $$\left| \frac{x}{|x|^p}-\frac{y}{|y|^p} \right|\le c|y-x|(|x|^{-p}+|y-x|^{-p})$$ where $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^N$. I have no trouble showing this for the case where $x^\top y<0$ (square both sides and use Jensen's inequality), but when $x^\top y>0$ I am not sure how to proceed. My plots in Desmos so far have been consistent with the above expression (I tried lots of $p$ values) for $x, y\in\mathbb{R}$ but I'm not sure if it's true in the most general ($\mathbb{R}^N$) case, and if it's true I don't know how to handle when $x^\top y>0$. Any advice would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the inequality holds, an example is
$$c=1+\max\left(1,-\frac{p}{2^{p+1}}\right)$$

---

**Proof:** We have the following $3$ cases.

**Case (1):** $x=0$ or $y=0$. The equality holds for $c=1$.

---

**Case (2):** $|x|\geq|y|>0$. Let $q=-p\geq0$, we have
$$\Big|x|x|^q-y|y|^q\Big|=\Big|(x-y)|x|^q+y\big(|x|^q-|y|^q\big)\Big|\leq|y-x|\cdot|x|^q+|y|\cdot\Big||y|^q-|x|^q\Big|.$$
Since $\big||y|-|x|\big|\leq|y-x|$, it is sufficient to find $c>0$ such that
$$|y|\cdot\Big||y|^q-|x|^q\Big|\leq c\big||y|-|x|\big|^{q+1}+(c-1)\big||y|-|x|\big|\cdot|x|^q.$$
Let $t=|x|/|y|\geq1$ and the above inequality is equivalent to
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad t^q-1\leq c(t-1)^{q+1}+(c-1)(t-1)t^q\quad\forall\,t\geq1,q\geq0.$$
Let $f(t)=c(t-1)^{q+1}+(c-1)(t-1)t^q-(t^q-1)$, we shall find $c$ such that $f(t)\geq0$ for $t\geq1$. Since $f(1)=0$, we only need $f'(t)\geq0$ for $t\geq1$. To this end, note that
$$f'(t)\geq0\ \Longleftrightarrow\ c(t-1)^q+(c-1)t^q\geq\frac{qc}{q+1}t^{q-1}.$$
Since $t\geq1$, it is sufficient to drop $c(t-1)^q$, which gives $(c-1)t\geq (qc)/(q+1)$ and hence $c\geq q+1$. This proves your inequality with $c=1-p$ for $|x|\geq|y|$.

---

**Case (3):** $|y|>|x|>0$. Follow the same steps with $t=|x|/|y|<1$, the inequality is equivalent to
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 1-t^q\leq c(1-t)^{q+1}+(c-1)(1-t)t^q\quad\forall\,t\in(0,1),q\geq0.$$
Let $c^*=c-1$, it is sufficient to have $1-t^q\leq c^*(1-t)^{q+1}+c^*(1-t)t^q$ and therefore
$$c^*\geq\frac{(1-t^q)/(1-t)}{(1-t)^q+t^q}=:\frac{N_2(t)}{N_1(t)}. $$
For $t\in[0,1]$ and $q\geq0$, it is easy to verify the following

- If $q\geq1$, $N_1$ is minimised at $t=1/2$ and $N_2$ is maximised at $t=1$ (in the sense of limit), hence $N_2/N_1\leq2^{q-1}q$;
- If $q<1$, $N_1$ is minimised at $t=0$ (or $1$) and $N_2$ is maximised at $t=0$, hence $N_2/N_1\leq1$.

To summarise, it is sufficient to have $c^*\geq\max(1,2^{q-1}q)$ and hence your inequality is proved with $c=\max(2,1-p/2^{p+1})$ for $|x|<|y|$.